# Cant stop kusama staking with enzyme in substrate

Tags: enzyme, substrate

can anybody help me?

I have not been able to stop the stakign of kusama on the substrate for two months, it remains in a queue and never stops it (I have an enzyme connected to it)

I think it may be an enzyme problem, because the wifi icon appears as disconnected when I am inside the substrate

Comment: I'd ask in the enzyme github or forum instead of SO.

Comment: No one answered for months on github :(